# How to fetch and split data of URL and set it to TextView in Android?

Tags: android

Actually I am trying to fetch data from a URL and have to split that data string using the `split("@")` method and have to set that data in TextView.

It's running without error, but it is showing nothing.

```
enter code here

package com.androidpeople.view;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;``
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WebViewExample extends Activity {
    String element1,element2,element3,element4,element5,element6;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView text1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView text2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView text3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView text4=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        TextView text5=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        TextView text6=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);

        String nextLine;
        URL url = null;
        URLConnection urlConn = null;
        InputStreamReader inStream = null;
        BufferedReader buff = null;

        // Create the URL obect that points
        // at the default file index.html
        if (nextLine !=null){
            String aColors[] = nextLine.split("@");

            element1= aColors[0];
            element2= aColors[1];
            element3= aColors[2];
            element4= aColors[3];
            element5= aColors[4];
            element6= aColors[5];
        }
    }
}

catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
text1.setText("text is" +element1);
text2.setText("text is" +element2);
text3.setText("text is" +element3);
text4.setText("text is" +element4);
text5.setText("text is" +element5);
text6.setText("text is" +element6);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Split method have to use like this :

```
 String aColors[] = nextLine.split("\\@");  

instead of
String aColors[] = nextLine.split("@");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks 4 reply but i think their is a problem in setText it's showing nothing in TextView.Could you help me in setting value in textview.

Comment: If the values element1 etc.. contains values then it must show. if not means check textview color if is same as layout background. Check once in xml by sample text and see actually textview are displaying or not.

Comment: Thanks again but color is different from background color and plz check my code whether it is fetching data from url or not and if there is another method to fetch data from url then plz provide me source code.